# How do I compare 2 numbers with more than 1 decimal in JavaScript?

Tags: if-statement, version-control, conditional-statements, decimal-point

I am trying to compare version numbers that range from 1.0 to 1.10.11, they range anywhere from 1.2 to 1.3.35 and I would like to write an if statement that could push() values between a range of 1.0 - 1.0.99 then 1.2. 
ie my code below :)

I keep trying different things but am not sure. I tried changing the numbers to string but I realise that makes no sense. I figure there has got be a simpler way. (I am junior dev btw so any advice would be helpful) Thanks in advance.

````
function sortVersion() {
 let sVw = document.getElementsByClassName('triangle-td-software-version');
 for(let vN of sVw) {
  let versionNumber = vN.innerText;
    if(versionNumber == 1.0 || versionNumber < 1.09.99 ){
        v1_0.push(versionNumber)
        console.log('V1_0 =', v1_0);
      }else if(versionNumber == 1.1.0 || versionNumber <= 1.1.35){
            v1_1.push(versionNumber);
            console.log('V1_1 =', v1_1);
          } else if(versionNumber == 1.2 || versionNumber <= 1.2.2){
                v1_2.push(versionNumber);
                console.log('V1_2 =', v1_2);
              }else if(versionNumber == 1.3 || versionNumber <= 1.3.11){
                    v1_3.push(versionNumber);
                        console.log('V1_3 =', v1_3);
                  }else if(versionNumber == 1.4){
                        v1_4.push(versionNumber);
                            console.log('V1_4 =', v1_4);
                    }

 }```
````

Comment: Split up the version number into separate parts, the compare part by part, left to right.

Comment: If I do that wont it cause 1.10.1 to be less than 1.3.11 where as our versions increment. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5.....1.10 , 1.11
I was hoping to compare just the first 3 places... so if its 1.2.3 I could just get all of the the 1.2's, if its 1.10.11 I could get all of the 1.10's in an array?? Am I not thinking right?

Comment: No, compare the parts *as numbers*, 1=1, 3<10, so 1.3.11 is less than 1.10.1.

Comment: How do I compare parts? Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: Split the version numbers into arrays, so that 1.1.35 becomes [1, 1, 35], split it as strings, convert each section into a number and store it in the array. Then compare array element to array element from two different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code in Swift that should work. It should be easy to translate it into JavaScript (not so familiar to me).
Since I did not know better, and just for fun, I wrote it recursively so that the number of subversions is arbitrary.

```
let versions = ["3.0", "1.0", "1.10.11", "3.1.5", "1.3.35", "1.2"]

// Convert your versions string to an array of versions, each represented by an array of ints. Store the version length
var versionLength = 0
var versionsInts: [[Int]] = []
for version in versions {
    let versionComponents = version.components(separatedBy: ".")
    if versionComponents.count > versionLength {
        versionLength = versionComponents.count
    }
    var versionInts: [Int] = []
    for versionComponent in versionComponents {
        versionInts.append(Int(versionComponent)!)
    }
    versionsInts.append(versionInts)
}

// Make each int array of the same length
for index in 0 ..< versionsInts.count {
    var versionInts = versionsInts[index]
    for _ in versionInts.count ..< versionLength {
        versionInts.append(0)
    }
    versionsInts[index] = versionInts
}

// Recursive helper function that compares 2 versions using a subindex
func cmp(version1: [Int], version2: [Int], subIndex: Int) -> Bool {
    if subIndex == version1.count { return true } // Both versions are the same, take any
    if version1[subIndex] < version2[subIndex] { return true } // ascending order
    if version1[subIndex] > version2[subIndex] { return false } // descending order
    return cmp(version1: version1, version2: version2, subIndex: subIndex+1) // If both versions up to now are the same, check next level
}

let sortedVersions = versionsInts.sorted(by: { (v1: [Int], v2: [Int]) -> Bool in
    return cmp(version1: v1, version2: v2, subIndex: 0) // recursively check versions
})
```

Output:

```
Printing description of sortedVersions:
▿ 6 elements
  ▿ 0 : 3 elements
    - 0 : 1
    - 1 : 0
    - 2 : 0
  ▿ 1 : 3 elements
    - 0 : 1
    - 1 : 2
    - 2 : 0
  ▿ 2 : 3 elements
    - 0 : 1
    - 1 : 3
    - 2 : 35
  ▿ 3 : 3 elements
    - 0 : 1
    - 1 : 10
    - 2 : 11
  ▿ 4 : 3 elements
    - 0 : 3
    - 1 : 0
    - 2 : 0
  ▿ 5 : 3 elements
    - 0 : 3
    - 1 : 1
    - 2 : 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using the str.split() method like this. But this pointed me in the right direction. Appreciate everyone.
~~~

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I ended up using the str.split() method like this. But this pointed me in the right direction. Appreciate everyone.

```
let v1_0 = [],
 v1_1 = [],
 v1_2 = [],
 v1_3 = [],
 v1_4 = [],
 v1_5 = [],
 v1_6 = [],
 v1_7 = [],
 v1_8 = [],
 v1_9 = [],
 v1_10 = [],
 v1_11 = [],
 v1_12 = [],
 what_are_you = [] ;

function sortVersion() {
 let sVw = document.getElementsByClassName('triangle-td-software-version');
 for(let vN of sVw) {
  let versionNumber = vN.innerText;
 if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] == 0){
      v1_0.push(versionNumber)

      }else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 2 ){
          v1_1.push(versionNumber);
           console.log(v1_1.length)
          } else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 3){
              v1_2.push(versionNumber);

              }else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 4){
                  v1_3.push(versionNumber);

                  }else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 5){
                      v1_4.push(versionNumber);

                      }else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 6){
                          v1_5.push(versionNumber);

                          }else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 7){
                              v1_6.push(versionNumber);

                              }else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 8){
                                  v1_7.push(versionNumber);

                                  }else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 9){
                                      v1_8.push(versionNumber);

                                      }else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 10){
                                          v1_9.push(versionNumber);

                                          }else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 11){
                                              v1_10.push(versionNumber);

                                              }else if(versionNumber.split(".")[1] > 10 || versionNumber.split(".")[1] < 0 || versionNumber.split(".")[1] == nil){
                                                  what_are_you.push(version);
                                                      console.log("Waht Are you!?!?", versionNumber);
                                                  }
                              }

            }//end of function
```

Comment: I then used  v1_#.length to populate the pie chart.

Comment: If your question is answered, I suggest that you accept any answer (including your own) so that the question is closed.